# Sitecore Azure PaaS webapp becomes unresponsive when Unicorn files copied

Tags: paas, unicorn

We are using `Unicorn` to sync Sitecore items between different Sitecore instances. We have created a separate Azure `DevOps release pipeline` dedicated only for copying Unicorn files and running the sync process. However, whenever the Unicorn files are copied into the Sitecore PaaS web app's directory using `KUDU APIs`, the web app becomes unresponsive (we assume it restarts) and throws 502 bad gateway error for all subsequent KUDU API calls. The Unicorn files used to get copied in `App_Data/Unicorn` folder. We moved the Unicorn folder out of the website root wwwroot folder but the issue still persists.

---

We connected with Microsoft Azure Support team and they confirmed that the issue is with the application worker process which becomes unresponsive. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: I've not had much success with those KUDU API calls. I'd be looking at using Web Deploy to deploy your files to where you need them to go. It has the added benefit of ensuring that if you move/delete unicorn files, the old files won't still be present on your server as it can use 'sync' so that you get exactly what's in your deployment package deployed to your target instance.

Comment: Are you deploying the Unicorn YML files to the CD app service? You should only be deploying them to your CM app service, syncing them to the master database and then publishing them to web which your CD app service reads from.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain, we are deploying Unicorn YML files to CM app service only.

Comment: @GhanendraSingh Ok good, wanted to make sure. I agree with Dave, I would deploy the Unicorn files as part of a webdeploy along with the rest of your application files. You would want them to go out at the same time anyway because the code and serialization should be tied together in version control. So your build tool should package it all up for deployment and webdeploy the whole thing together.